# macOS Menu bar text rendering breaks often

Tags: macos, display

I have no idea what causes this, but every few hours, something to do with how macOS displays text in the Menu fails to display. Additionally some windows, such as the shut down dialog box just show up as black.

This problem is solved by logging out and back in again, but not by simply locking the OS. I would presume that restarting also fixes it.

What causes this to happen, and what can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/347698/edit) your question to include the exact model of Mac you're running and the version of macOS you have installed? Also, it'd be good if you could explain exactly what the image is of?

Comment: as @Monomeeth said, you should provide more info, about what version of macOS you have and what kind of hardware. Most likely there is something going on with your graphics driver or the switching mechanism from the internal to discrete graphics if there is one, on your Mac. Do you run anything which is either OpenGL or 3D app?